# Error in saving to Database for combo box

Tags: mysql, vb.net, workbench

I'm receiving the following error:

> error : you have an error in your sql syntax.check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOFTWARE DEVELOPER' at line 1.

This is my code:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim conStr As String = ("server=localhost;username=root;password=rootfnc;database=one")
    Try
        Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

        For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count
            con.Open()

            Dim sqls As String
            sqls = "insert into one.initial_nom (idinitial_nom, f_name, s_name, th_name, fo_name, app_no, adm_type) values ('" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "', '" & TextBox5.Text & ",'" & ComboBox1.Items(i).ToString & "')"
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqls, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Does anyone know what the error is caused by?

Comment: Please provide more details. When are you receiving the error? What are you trying to do??

Comment: i'm trying adding some record with combo box.when i clicked the save button...error : you have an error in your sql syntax.check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOFTWARE DEVELOPER' at line 1.

Comment: In your items count do, Items.Count-1

Comment: still same with that error

Comment: After Items(i) do Items(i).Text.ToString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't properly enclosing all the values you're inserting into the string in apostrophes:

```
... '" & TextBox5.Text & "_,'" & ComboBox1.Items(i).ToString & "')"
```

Notice where I've put the underscore, after `TextBox5.Text` is concatenated onto the string: there should be a closing apostrophe there, before the comma.

Now, the fact is that you shouldn't be concatenating SQL commands together from user input in the first place, and should instead be preparing the statement using the `SqlCommand`'s [`SqlParameter` collection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-parameters). Here's a simplified example:

```
sqls = "insert into tableName (column1) values (@parameterName)"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqls, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@parameterName", TextBox5.Text))
' ... 
' <snip - set other parameters as needed>
' ...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Dang ticks, nice catch!